# Download multiple images from multiple URLS in dictionary python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to write a function that fetches the URLs of images from dynamodb and download them using the url into a folder in my machine.

Below is my code:-

```
#reference dynamodb
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
#point at music table
table = dynamodb.Table('Music')
#get image url values from dynamodb
imageUrl = table.scan(AttributesToGet=['img_url'])
#add urls found into dict
urls=[]
urls.append(imageUrl)

#print(urls)

#download all images from their urls
for url in urls:
    url = imageUrl['Items']
    image = url[0]['img_url']
    file_name = image.split('/')[-1]
    response = requests.get(image)
    file = open("/Users/abdotech/Desktop/images/"+file_name, "wb")
    for chunk in response:
      file.write(chunk)


    file.close()
```

This code downloads only one image from the first url only, although I am iterating through a dictionary list of several image urls. the print(urls) returns all of the image urls found in the database, so thats how i know that my dictionary has all the needed urls.

So basically my bug lies in the for statement and I can't figure out what might be causing the issue.

Thanks in advance.

EDITS:

```
for url in imageUrl:
    url = imageUrl['Items']
    image = url['img_url']
    file_name = image.split('/')[-1]
    response = requests.get(image)
    file = open("/Users/abdotech/Desktop/images/"+file_name, "wb")
    for chunk in response:
      file.write(chunk)


    file.close()
```

error:TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Your `urls` list only contains one thing, so the loop is only going to iterate once. The fact that you had to write `url[0]` should have been a clue to that.  `imageUrl` is already a list.  Just write `urls = imageUrl`, change `url[0]` to `url` and it should work.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for the reply, I have better understanding of the problem, yet it doesn't work.
Check out my edits.

Comment: You have `for url in imageUrl`, but you immediately ignore the `url` loop variable and replace it with `url = imageUrl['Items']`. That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't properly iterating through the results.  The response from the scan contains the list of Items you need to iterate over, you don't need to create another `urls` list for this.  You also are hardcoding the `0` index in your loop so it's always grabbing the first item of the list instead of the current item in the loop.

Try something like this:

```
#reference dynamodb
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
#point at music table
table = dynamodb.Table('Music')
#get image url values from dynamodb
imageUrl = table.scan(AttributesToGet=['img_url'])

#print(urls)

#loop through all items returned by dynamodb
for url in imageUrl['Items']:
    image = url['img_url']
    file_name = image.split('/')[-1]
    response = requests.get(image)
    file = open("/Users/abdotech/Desktop/images/"+file_name, "wb")
    for chunk in response:
      file.write(chunk)


    file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues going on here.
`error:TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` is telling you that you're trying to access a list item with a string. I think your variable names aren't helping you here either.

Basically, your `url` variable is being set to the list of dicts in the dynamodb response, and you're ignoring the `url` variable you tried to set while iterating your result set.

Also, your `for url in urls` is going to loop once because of your `urls.append(imageUrl)` since `imageUrl` here was actually the dynamo response dict.

Something like this ought to help.

```py
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Music')
scan_response = table.scan(AttributesToGet=['img_url'])

for record in scan_response["Items"]:
    img_url = record["img_url"]
    file_name = img_url.split('/')[-1]
    response = requests.get(img_url)
    with open("/Users/abdotech/Desktop/images/" + file_name, "wb") as file:
        for chunk in response:
          file.write(chunk)
```

P.S. use `with` statements when you can.

Comment: Thanks Kirk for your reply, Your explanation was very thorough and made me realise my mistake!